# How to create Java POJO class dynamically?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, creation

I have seen a post in this website regarding the dynamic POJO generation. I have the similar requirement now.

I have some tables in the database. I want to have a POJO class for each table with fields and corresponding getters and setters. These classes are to be created dynamically. Once these classes are created I should use those setters and getters in other class to get and set the data and return the Java object.

I have seen BCEL, CGLIB and some other open source tools for this, but couldnt find the proper example. Can you help me?

Comment: StackOverflow works as a community to help everyone by keeping its questions and answers on the site, so others can benefit. Please don't ask for email correspondence.

Comment: I added a downvote because the whole concept is such a bad idea that I can't think what else to do.  Don't codegen, don't use beans, don't use setters and getters (Btw, a POJO with no business logic that has setters and getters is called a bean pattern, the word pojo is only really needed to differentiate a bean (which needs setters and getters) from a Plain Old Java Object with no requirements whatsoever. What you should use is a hashmap for your specific case since the bean will be created after the code is finished (By user input, you said) or some similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at any of the ORM (Object Relational Mapping) frameworks out there that have been created for just this purpose? [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or the Java EE 6 standard [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), for instance. It sounds like you are starting down on a path of re-inventing something that is both pretty complex and very time consuming - never a good idea.

UPDATE: in response to comment

Well, I can only say that you guys are building yourselves into a world of hurt. Consider:

1. If you rely on completely dynamic classes, you are you going to reference those classes and objects from other classes? Through reflection? And how are you going to keep track of all the created classes, their names and the names of their setters and getters?
2. What happens when you have to restart your system? How are you going to re-create all those dynamic classes?
3. With a completely dynamic database, how are you going to be able to do any performance optimization on it? Like indexing, for instance.

I can only strongly advise you to re-think your architecture. Dynamic datamodels are a mess to begin with, and next to impossible to maintain, optimize and debug. I've seen systems based on it and it's not pretty. IBM Lotus WCM is a prime example of data model horror. A properly designed and normalized relational model will be better in 99,99999999% of the cases.

Combining this with a harness of dynamic, run time ORM classes will be utterly impossible to maintain (and understand).

Comment: Yaa but to use hibernate and other ORM tools, that tables has to be defined earlier. But in my case tables will be generated dynamically from user actions and so the corresponding classes also has to be generated dynamically.

Comment: @Pap is absolutely right.  I had a huge answer I'm not going to send because it isn't an answer, but basically what you want to use is a hashmap.  If you are creating your objects from user input, the only possible advantage of genning a class instead of using a hash (Type safety) is voided because you will have to access the fields reflectively anyway!