# How dynamic Pojo will decide the exact mapped relation?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Let there be a SQL query for which I need to generate a dynamic Pojo class. So here is my question:
SQL query: select msisdn,code,user from Example;

this table(Example) is having 13 columns. So how will I decide the mapping for not given columns. I mean will the dynamic pojo be created or there will be some exception. Is it compulsory to map all the columns of a relation to the pojo class?. I am new to hibernate and just heard about Dynamic Pojos. This question is just for the sake of knowledge.

**UPDATE :**

Let Me Clear this:

I have an app A(say, simple java app uses Oracle DB) and another as B(developed in hibernate). A interacts with B to fetch or store its data instead of directly interacting to the Oracle DB. It calls a method select(say) of B passing the SQL query(to be operated on) to it. A receives the query and Generates a dynamic POJO for the given table in the query.

**Now my question is that:**
Will the POJO class be Generated on the basis of 4-given/requested columns in the query even if the table has 13 or more than 4 columns. If yes then how will this mapping take place. Is my question right? Am I thinking for a possible thing to happen?

Comment: [explaination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120748/how-to-create-java-pojo-class-dynamically) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653770/creating-dynamic-pojos-and-set-values-to-it)

Comment: Are you asking how to query a subset of fields as a tuple from a mapped POJO entity managed by Hibernate?

Comment: @ Naros I have Updated my question please revert.

Comment: @ Naros you may also consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178391/create-simple-pojo-classes-bytecode-at-runtime-dynamically)

Comment: @v.ladynev please have a look at the problem